# Gulp issues with javascript

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify

As the title says, I'm currently using gulp in my project. Each time I try and compile the entire thing, it throws an error at me. I went through the code, it doesn't seem to have issues (and it works, above all else). When I remove a single function from my code, it then compiles it without any issues.

```
/* Main JS */

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "resources/json/main-nav.json",
    method: "GET",
    type: "JSON",
    success: function(data){
      loadNav(data);
    }
  });
});

/* Functions NOTE: WHEN I REMOVE THIS FUNCTION, IT COMPILES WITHOUT ISSUES.*/
function loadNav(items){
  let writeNav = "";
  for(let item of items){
    writeNav += `<li><a href="${item.href}">${item.text}</a></li>`;
  }
  $(".navigation-list").html(writeNav);
}
```

EDIT:
Forgot the actual error:

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
    at createError (/var/www/html/guitar-store/node_modules/gulp-uglify/lib/create-error.js:6:14)
    at apply (/var/www/html/guitar-store/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/lodash/_apply.js:16:25)
    at wrapper (/var/www/html/guitar-store/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/lodash/_createCurry.js:41:12)
    at /var/www/html/guitar-store/node_modules/gulp-uglify/lib/minify.js:55:15
    at DestroyableTransform._transform (/var/www/html/guitar-store/node_modules/gulp-uglify/composer.js:12:19)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/var/www/html/guitar-store/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:184:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (/var/www/html/guitar-store/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:172:83)
    at doWrite (/var/www/html/guitar-store/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:428:64)
    at writeOrBuffer (/var/www/html/guitar-store/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:417:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/var/www/html/guitar-store/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:334:11)
```

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: My bad, I edited it in @mbuechmann

Comment: I'd start by simplifying the function and seeing if it fails. Does it fail with `function loadNav(items){}`? How about `function loadNav(items){
  let writeNav = "";
}`? This way, you can identify the line that's causing issues.

Comment: It breaks after it reaches the `let writeNav = " ";` line

Comment: I suspect, then, that you don't have Babel set up right, and it's choking on the ES6 syntax there.

Comment: As @ceejayoz mentions, the `for...of` syntax is ES6. Change that to something like a vanilla `for` loop or use babel